# I dont understand the motion of this particle

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image]

I have found the velocity to be equal to $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \cos t$ and acceleration to be equal to $\sin t$. I am not sure how to find the remaining questions.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT.** An object whose position is given by $f(t)$ is accelerating if $f''(t)>0$ because then its velocity ($f'(t)$) would be increasing.

As for the last part, I assume what they mean by 'direction' here is whether the particle is moving 'up' or 'down'. To think what direction the particle is moving, it would be moving in the direction of its tangent line. The slope of the tangent line is given by $f'(t)$. So if the particle is moving downward its tangent line has negative slope, i.e. $f'(t)<0$, and if it is moving upward its tangent line has positive slop, i.e. $f'(t)>0$.

It can also help to compare what you are doing to the actual plot of the particles movement. [See this graph here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20Sqrt%5B2%5D%2F2*t-Sin%5Bt%5D%20from%20t%3D0%20to%20t%3D2*Pi).

Comment: @404man Just below the plot in the link provided, wolfram shows the formula to calculate the total distance (for part b). You would need to change the integration limit, so it shows from $0$ to $\pi$ instead of from $0$ to $2\pi$. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your answers to (a) are correct. $f'(x)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-cos(t)$ and $f''(x)=sin(t)$.

Now, (b) is asking what is the total distance this particle travels over the first $\pi$ seconds. This is not to be confused with the concept of *displacement*. The question is not asking how far the particle is from it's starting point. Instead, it's asking the entire distance the particle has covered, even if it's back-tracked. An example, you walk to your car which is $10m$ away from you, and then you walk back to your starting point. Your *displacement* would be $0$, but the distance you've covered would be $20m$. Now, for your problem, we look at the velocity function of this particle which happens to be:

$$v(t)=f'(x)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\cos(t)$$

So we set this function equal to zero because we want to see where our critical points are

$$0=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\cos(t)\Rightarrow \cos(t)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

We're only interested in the first $\pi$ seconds so our interval is $[0,\pi]$. What values of $t$ make this statement true on the interval $[0,\pi]$? We will call this value $j$, so we say $t=j$. With this information, we look back at our position function. Our velocity function can vary in behavior. The velocity could be positive for $1$s and then be negative for $0.4$s before returning to a positive value. This is where backtracking can occur and is lost in the position function. We know when the velocity is $0$ (i.e. a critical point) we are guaranteed the time prior that, the velocity is either increasing, decreasing, or constant. So we can evaluate our position function at $t=j$

$$f(j)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(j)-\sin(j)$$

This is our distance covered from $t=0$ to $t=j$. At this point our velocity might change and we might go backwards-- so we retrace our steps, but still cover some distance. We want to know this distance. Since our velocity function had only one critical point on our interval, we are interested in the position covered by the remainder time which is given by $t=\pi-j$. Thus, we evaluate our position function at this time.

$$f(\pi-j)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(\pi-j)-\sin(\pi-j)$$

We add these values to find our total distance covered. $x_{tot}=f(j)+f(\pi-j)$.

(c) When is velocity increasing? That is to say, when is it's derivative positive? You found the acceleration function already, so how do we find when it's increasing?

(d) Simply wants to know how many times the sign of our velocity changed over the critical points. From the interval before one critical point to the interval after, and so on. How many times did this sign change? You need to test values on the intervals. We found one critical point so let's use that (THOUGH THERE MAY BE MORE SINCE OUR INTERVAL IS NOW $[0,2\pi]$). What is the sign of the velocity from $[0,j]$, well we pick a random number in this interval and evaluate it the velocity function. That will give us a positive or negative number. That sign, positive or negative is the direction of the velocity. So with all critical points on $[0,2\pi]$ we have to look at the interval between endpoints to critical points, to critical points, to endpoints. (i.e. on intervals like $[0,j], [j,g], [g,2\pi]$, say g is another critical point). We have to see how many times the sign of the velocity function evaluated changes.

I understand this may seem long, but being thorough is important for your understanding. It's not a simple answer to the questions you've asked. It's extremely easy to get confused, especially since this is an applied problem to physics and not just a pure math example.

Comment: I am confused now as what value or values to use for J?

Comment: J maybe be more than one value but it is the critical points of your derivative. When you set a derivative equal to 0 and solve for the variable, you're solving for critical points.